# Firebase dynamic links template for subdomens

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Is it possible to use dynamic template of subdomains in firebase dynamic links, such as registering a *.my-app.page.link domain and so that the links work on any URL (use any string instead of * )?
For example I have the app at my-app.com which registered at firebase at my-app.page.link
and i create feature contours for different tasks such as feature-565785.my-app.com or feature-609000.my-app.com. Is it possible to do dynamic links working on every feature contour?

Regards

didn't find out anything

Comment: While there is merit to getting you an answer, if your project doesn't already use [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links), you should not use the feature as [it is deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) and will be removed in a future release. I encourage you to look into an alternate way of achieving your task. Unfortunately I do not know of any alternatives at this time that I can point you towards.